# RegEx at Google Tag Manager

Tags: regex, tags, google-tag-manager

I'm using Google Tag Manager to configure events for an e-commerce and I need search for the word "trash" in the string below:

`"SVGSVGElement: html > body.template-home.overflow-none > div.theme-w" + "ide#container > form.js-ajax-cart-panel.js-fullscreen-modal.ajax-car" + "t-container.modal-right.modal-xs.modal-xs-right.modal-xs-right-out#a" + "jax-cart-details > div.modal-xs-dialog > div.modal-content > div.aja" + "x-cart-body.modal-right-body.modal-xs-body > div.js-ajax-cart-list.a" + "jax-cart-table.pull-left > div.js-cart-item.js-cart-item-shippable.a" + "jax-cart-item > div.ajax-cart-item-delete-col.cart-delete-container." + "ajax-cart-item-col.text-right > button.cart-btn-delete.ajax-cart-btn" + "-delete.pull-right.p-top-none > div.cart-delete-svg-icon.svg-icon-te" + "xt > svg.svg-trash-icon"`

Question:

What expression do I use to search for the word "trash" in the string at Google Tag Manager?

Thanks for listening!

I have already tested the following RegEx:

`\btrash\b  /(trash\d+(\.\d)*)/I  /trash/g`

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow!

try this: `\b\S*trash\S*\b` (with a global modifier)

demo: https://regex101.com/r/AtfgvE/1

It will find any word (separated by spaces) that has the word trash in it (so for example `svg.svg-trash-icon` will be matched)

Comment: Thank for the answer, Akash

But it doesn't work...

The Google Tag Manager, for some reason, is not understanding the regex.

The config is like this: 

Click element matches RegEx \b\S*trash\S*\b

Answer (score 0):

Because your trigger is `{{Click Element}}`

It's not a string or text that you see on the preview.

If you want to target this element `svg.svg-trash-icon`

I would suggest you use:

`Click Element` `Match CSS Selector` `svg.svg-trash-icon`

OR

`Click Element` `Match CSS Selector` `svg[class*='trash']`

// This would match all svg element that class contains trash